# MongoDB MapReduce Composite Key Issue

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

First, I am new to MongoDB and I would like to do big-data analysis with MongoDB.
In my question I have a MonogoDB collection with the following data

```
 db.EIRLogs2.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57772d1f152d447caa142fbf"), "NAME" : "Kamal", "AGE" : 20, "MARKS" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57772d1f152d447caa142fc0"), "NAME" : "Kamal", "AGE" : 30, "MARKS" : 300 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57772d1f152d447caa142fc1"), "NAME" : "Sunil", "AGE" : 30, "MARKS" : 300 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57772d1f152d447caa142fc2"), "NAME" : "Sunil", "AGE" : 30, "MARKS" : 400 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57772d1f152d447caa142fc3"), "NAME" : "Kasun", "AGE" : 20, "MARKS" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57772d1f152d447caa142fc4"), "NAME" : "Kamal", "AGE" : 20, "MARKS" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57772d1f152d447caa142fc5"), "NAME" : "Kasun", "AGE" : 20, "MARKS" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57772d1f152d447caa142fc6"), "NAME" : "Sunimal", "AGE" : 30, "MARKS" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57772d1f152d447caa142fc7"), "NAME" : "Kamal", "AGE" : 20, "MARKS" : 600 }
```

And I am expecting to apply a MapReduce function to above data set and get an answer as below

```
{ "_id" : "Kamal",   "AGE" : 20, "value" : 800 }
{ "_id" : "Kamal",   "AGE" : 30, "value" : 300 }
{ "_id" : "Kasun",   "AGE" : 20, "value" : 200 }
{ "_id" : "Sunil",   "AGE" : 30, "value" : 700 }
{ "_id" : "Sunimal", "AGE" : 20, "value" : 100 }
```

I used below code to get above answer but it returned an error

```
db.EIRLogs2.mapReduce(  
      function() { 
           emit( {this.NAME,this.AGE}, this.MARKS ); 
      }, 
      function(key,values){ 
         return Array.sum(values)
      }, 
      { out: "ETom" } 
)
```

I got the following error

```
Sat Jul  2 09:17:32 SyntaxError: missing : after property id (shell):1
```

I highly appreciate your help to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object literal in your `emit` is not a valid expression as you don't specify the names. The following should fix your problem:

```
db.EIRLogs2.mapReduce.mapReduce(  
      function() { 
           emit(
              { name: this.NAME, age: this.AGE }, 
              this.MARKS
           ); 
      }, 
      function(key,values) { 
         return Array.sum(values)
      },
      {
          out: "ETom"
      }
)
```